# nativescript: how to add extension while using Downloader plugin

Tags: download, nativescript

Hello i need to download an audio file from an external URL and it works but without the .mp3 extension, which is required for the player to recognize it, here is my code:

```
getAudio(token:String,interestPointId:string,link:string, audioId):string{

    const downloadManager = new Downloader();
    var path:string;

    const imageDownloaderId = downloadManager.createDownload({
        url:link        

      });

      downloadManager
      .start(imageDownloaderId, (progressData: ProgressEventData) => {
        console.log(`Progress : ${progressData.value}%`);
        console.log(`Current Size : ${progressData.currentSize}%`);
        console.log(`Total Size : ${progressData.totalSize}%`);
        console.log(`Download Speed in bytes : ${progressData.speed}%`);
      })
      .then((completed: DownloadEventData) => {


        path=completed.path;           
        console.log(`Image : ${completed.path}`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
    return path;    

}
```

is just a modified version from the example (https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-downloader)

the goal is to download the file and get the path to it while the name should be something like ~path/idAudio.mp3

any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the fileName and the path on the createDownload it is not documented (I forgot) there is [interface](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-downloader/blob/master/src/downloader.common.ts#L67) you can use so what you need to is the following also i would recommend you not try to save the file to the project root e.g `~/blah/blah.mp3` that would fail on a real ios device

```
downloadManager.createDownload({
        url:link        
        path:somePath,
       fileName: 'idAudio.mp3'
      }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem, i also had to add '/' before the filename tho.